# What happens to the hollow nerve cord?

Tags: brain, development

The dorsal nerve cord of vertebrates is a hollow structure that develops into the nervous system. This embryonic tissue is hollow and I wonder what happens to this 'hollow' later?

Does it form the ventricles of brain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "hollow" i.e. the neural canal develops into the ventricles, the cerebral aqueduct and the spinal canal ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventricular_system#Development); also see [this](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/Neural_System_Development) site).

For a more authoritative reference, see this book by Haines and Ard<sup>†</sup> (page 82 onwards in google books; google book links are apparently transient and they expire; therefore I didn't provide one).

---

<sup>†</sup> Haines, Duane E., and M. D. Ard. *[Fundamental neuroscience for basic and clinical applications](https://evolve.elsevier.com/cs/product/9781437702941).* Philadelphia, PA: Elsevier/Saunders, 2013. ISBN: 9781437702941